# How do I get the url of the image tag in Java?

Tags: java, json, gson, geojson

The ImageUrl is:

[image: https://res.cloudinary.com/swiss-unihockey/image/upload/t_club_logo/gin0rst7ocrcuioryacs.png]

The JsonObject:

```
{  
   "type":"table",
   "subtype":"attribute_list",
   "doc":"https://api-v2.swissunihockey.ch/api/doc/attribute_list",
   "data":{  
      "context":null,
      "headers":[  
         {  
            "text":"Name",
            "key":"teamname",
            "long":"Name",
            "short":"Name",
            "prefer":"fit"
         },
         {  
            "text":"Logo",
            "key":"logo_url",
            "long":"Logo",
            "short":"Logo",
            "prefer":"fit"
         },
         {  
            "text":"Webseite",
            "key":"website_url",
            "long":"Webseite",
            "short":"Webseite",
            "prefer":"fit"
         },
         {  
            "text":"Teamportrait",
            "key":"portrait",
            "long":"Teamportrait",
            "short":"Teamportrait",
            "prefer":"fit"
         },
         {      
            "text":"Liga",
            "key":"liga",
            "long":"Liga",
            "short":"Liga",
            "prefer":"fit"
         },
         {  
            "text":"Anschrift",
            "key":"address",
            "long":"Anschrift",
            "short":"Anschrift",
            "prefer":"fit"
         }
      ],
      "title":"MR Krauchthal II",
      "subtitle":null,
      "tabs":[  

      ],
      "slider":null,
      "regions":[  
         {  
            "text":null,
            "rows":[  
               {  
                  "highlight":false,
                  "cells":[  
                     {  
                        "text":[  
                           "MR Krauchthal II"
                        ]
                     },
                     {  
                        "image":{  
                           "alt":"",
                           "url":"https://res.cloudinary.com/swiss-unihockey/image/upload/t_club_logo/gin0rst7ocrcuioryacs.png"
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "url":{  
                           "href":null,
                           "text":"Webseite"
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "image":{  
                           "alt":"",
                           "url":null
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "text":[  
                           "4. Liga"
                        ]
                     },
                     {  
                        "text":[  
                           "MR Krauchthal",
                           "Thomas"
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a JSON parser. There are several libraries you can use for that like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Here some basic Json handling with Gson:

```
JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(myJsonString).getAsJsonObject();  // will parse your string to json and return it as a JsonObject
JsonObject data = json.get("data").getAsJsonObject(); // returns the jsonObject that contains everything in "data":{...}
JsonArray regions = data.get("regions").getAsJsonArray();  // to get an array like "regions"
for(int i=0;i<regions.size();i++){   // loop through the array
    JsonObject region = regions.get(i).getAsJsonObject();  // get any element in the array (as JsonObject)
    String text= region.get("text").getAsString();  // get a JsonElement from your JsonObject and read it as a String (like "text")
}
```

it does not seem very "clean" or "easy" and other Json libraries will do this differently, but I would recommend this way if you don't want the whole "data" object to be parsed in a POJO. All you have to do now is, use the methods I showed you to walk through your json until you get the "url" or any other element you want.